# PHP Variables Lost in Files Included with Wordpress Functions

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

I am creating a admin theme for Wordpress, so I have set the new admin stylesheet using;

```
wp_admin_css_color(
    'infusion',
    _x( 'infusion', 'admin color scheme' ),
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/css/' . INFCOLOUR . '/colors-infusion.php',
    array( '#333', '#444', '#0074a2', '#2ea2cc' )
);
```

(INFCOLOUR has been assigned and is working properly). 
The PHP/CSS file has this as a header;

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>
```

The CSS is working correctly, but variables which are defined in the file where wp_admin_css_color(); is defined, cannot be used. Also, I cannot use a function which I have also defined in the same document. This just throws a fatal error in the style sheet. How can I carry these variables and functions through into the PHP/CSS document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved.

Instead of attaching my admin style sheet in the wp_admin_css_color() function, I attached a blank css file. This clears all old css without assigning any new ones. I then simply appended the admin style sheet to the admin_head hook, giving a nice little workaround: no problems so far, but I will update this if anything arises.

Result: Admin theme works exactly as before, and PHP variable now work as well.